# Deferred promise AJAX loop then() never happens

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I'm trying to use a deferred promise in an AJAX loop because using async: false is locking up the page. I've poked around at other similar uses but I don't understand  why $.when().apply().then() never executes.

```
    var userData = {};  
    userData.user1 = {"creds":{"userid":"user1@test.com","password":"user1pass","country":"us"}};
    userData.user2 = {"creds":{"userid":"user2@test.com","password":"user2pass","country":"mx"}};
    userData.user3 = {"creds":{"userid":"user3@test.com","password":"user3pass","country":"ca"}};
    function loginUser(credentials){
        var def = new $.Deferred();
        requests = [];
        $.each(credentials, function(k, v){
            var promise = $.ajax({
                url : '/path/to/my/uri', 
                type : 'post',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                data : JSON.stringify(v)
            });
            requests.push(promise); 
        });
        console.log(requests);
        // check if all ajax calls have finished
        $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
            // this never happens
            def.resolve();
            return def.promise();
            console.log('the request is done');
        });
    }
    loginUser(userData);


//updated snippet
var userData = {};  
userData.user1 = {"creds":{"userid":"user1@test.com","password":"user1pass","country":"us"}};
userData.user2 = {"creds":{"userid":"user2@test.com","password":"user2pass","country":"mx"}};
userData.user3 = {"creds":{"userid":"user3@test.com","password":"user3pass","country":"ca"}};
function loginUser(credentials){
    var requests = $.map(credentials, function(k, v){
    return $.ajax({
            url : '/path/to/my/uri', 
            type : 'post',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify(k)
        });
    });
    console.log(requests);
    // return a promise that will resolve when all ajax calls are done
    return $.when.apply($, requests);
}

loginUser(userData).done(function() {
// all logins completed here
console.log('inside done');
}).fail(function() {
// will be called if any login failed
console.log('inside fail');
});

// current syncronous functionality
function loadUrls(credentials){
    $.each(credentials, function(k, v){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/path/to/my/uri', 
            type : 'post',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('body').append('<a target="_blank" href="'+data.userInfo+'">'+data.userName+' '+k+'</a><br />');
            },
            data : JSON.stringify(v),
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                return;                 
            },
            async : false      
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure all requests are sent and handled successfully? Try changing `then` to `done` or attaching a `fail` handler as well as `then`.

Comment: You should be returning `def.promise()` at the end of loginUser outside of the `$.when` if you want to use it elsewhere, but that shouldn't prevent the log statement from occurring.

Comment: no, but the `return` call will...

Comment: @orzechowskid Doh! You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your log statement in here:

```
    $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
        // this never happens
        def.resolve();
        return def.promise();
        console.log('the request is done');
    });
```

will never happen because it's right after a `return` statement.

Perhaps you meant to return `def.promise()` from `loginUser()`.  But, alas, there's really no reason to create this extra deferred at all.  `$.when()` already returns a promise that can be used in this way.

---

Here's what I think you might actually want:

```
var userData = {};  
userData.user1 = {"creds":{"userid":"user1@test.com","password":"user1pass","country":"us"}};
userData.user2 = {"creds":{"userid":"user2@test.com","password":"user2pass","country":"mx"}};
userData.user3 = {"creds":{"userid":"user3@test.com","password":"user3pass","country":"ca"}};
function loginUser(credentials){
    var requests = [];
    $.each(credentials, function(k, v){
        var promise = $.ajax({
            url : '/path/to/my/uri', 
            type : 'post',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify(v)
        });
        requests.push(promise); 
    });
    console.log(requests);
    // return a promise that will resolve when all ajax calls are done
    return $.when.apply($, requests);
}

loginUser(userData).done(function() {
   // all logins completed here
}).fail(function() {
   // will be called if any login failed
});
```

Or, as Benjamin Gruenbaum suggested, you can shorten the code a bit by using `$.map()` instead of `$.each()`.

```
var userData = {};  
userData.user1 = {"creds":{"userid":"user1@test.com","password":"user1pass","country":"us"}};
userData.user2 = {"creds":{"userid":"user2@test.com","password":"user2pass","country":"mx"}};
userData.user3 = {"creds":{"userid":"user3@test.com","password":"user3pass","country":"ca"}};
function loginUser(credentials){
    var requests = $.map(credentials, function(k, v){
        return $.ajax({
            url : '/path/to/my/uri', 
            type : 'post',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify(v)
        });
    });
    console.log(requests);
    // return a promise that will resolve when all ajax calls are done
    return $.when.apply($, requests);
}

loginUser(userData).done(function() {
   // all logins completed here
}).fail(function() {
   // will be called if any login failed
});
```

---

If what you were saying is that your `$.when.done()` handler never got called (even after you put the `console.log()` statement in a place that it will get executed), then the only way that happens is if one of your ajax calls does not complete successfully.  You can watch for that by adding a `.fail()` handler in addition to a `.done()` handler.

---

If what you're really trying to do with your multiple logins is to just find out if at least one login that succeeds (even if the others fail), then you will need different logic for detecting that condition because `$.when()` will only tell you if all promises were resolved or if any promise was rejected.  It won't tell you if at least one was accepted.  To do that, we'd have to know what happens in the ajax call if the login is rejected.  Does the ajax call still succeed, but the results show that the login failed?  If so, then you'd have to examine the data passed to the `.done()` handler to see if at least one login succeeded.

Comment: I'd refactor this $.each to a `.map` so  `return $.when.apply($.map(credentials, function( k,v){ return $.ajax(...` other than that very nice answer addressing the issues OP is having with promises. Spot on about the deferred anti pattern and addressing the real issues OP is having.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I added your `$.map()` suggestion as a further optimization.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, got caught up in something after posting. So, the return statement above the console.log() was obvious mistake. I guess I didn't realize done() would not happen if any request failed. I don't get why the requests complete, albeit slowly, when async is set to false, but when trying to retain the state using the promise() method some requests fail. Shouldn't the state of the request be the same in both cases, just faster page load when dealing with a set of async promise objects, that should have the same state as when async is false?

Comment: @neridaj - Changing things from async to blocking often changes the sequence of events in the code so code often has to be written to work one way or the other.  Please design for async Ajax.  Your users will severely thank you because their browser page won't lock and make them think maybe the site hung during the ajax calls (particularly if there's any slowness in their connection or your server).

Comment: This still doesn't work. Even if all requests are 200 done() never gets called. If one request gets a 503 does this mean all the 200 requests are garbage? Is there a better way to loop ajax calls because this is not working.`inside fail
XHR Loaded (authenticate - 200 OK - 351.0608673095703ms - 311B) VM8380:3
XHR Loaded (authenticate - 200 OK - 450.9708881378174ms - 311B) VM8386:3
XHR Loaded (authenticate - 200 OK - 483.80398750305176ms - 311B)'

Comment: @neridaj - this concept works just fine.  If you want help debugging your particular code, you will have to share the exact code you're using so we can see what you're doing.  The way `$.when()` is designed is that all requests must succeed for it to call the `.done()` handler.  If any single request fails, it will call the `.fail()` handler.  That's just how it is coded.  You could write your own version of a `$.when()` like function that behaved differently.

Comment: `loginUser(userData).done(function() {
// all logins completed here
console.log('inside done');
}).fail(function() {
// will be called if any login failed
console.log('inside fail');
});`

Comment: @neridaj - we would need to see ALL your code for this operation.  And, please don't put multi-line code in comments as it is hard to read.  Use the edit button and add it to the end of your question and then add a comment directed at whomever you're responding to to announce that you added the code to the end of your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Sorry for the messy comments, I've posted a full snippet below the original. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @neridaj - what exactly do you want to pass to the Ajax call for the `data`?  Right now, you're passing `{"creds":{"userid":"user1@test.com","password":"user1pass","country":"us"}}`.  Is that what you want to pass or do you want to pass this: `{"userid":"user1@test.com","password":"user1pass","country":"us"}}`?

Comment: @jfriend00 - So, basically I want to loop over an object of user credentials and upon successful login build a list of urls that link to a new window which displays their info. The api accepts the request data in this form: `{"creds":{"userid":"user1@test.com","password":"user1pass","country":"us"}}`.

Comment: @neridaj - Do you require successful login to all the credentials or only to one of them?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sometimes, some of the requests timeout with a 503. In that case I don't want to append a url. Currently, there are 16 user creds objects. This will continue to increase, so I need to figure out how to do this asyncronously.

Comment: @neridaj - you didn't answer my question.  Do you want to know if all 16 succeed?  Or if at least one of them succeeds?  You take a very different approach depending upon the answer.  Right now, I think you should probably ask a new question that more completely describes what you're trying to do and what you want help with.

Comment: @jfriend00 - If one of the requests succeeds, then append that user url. If none of the requests succeed, then don't append any user urls. If all of the requests succeed, then append all user urls. For each successful request, append a url with that user info.

Comment: @neridaj - OK, that's not the question you asked here and would have little to do with `$.when()`.  Like I said, since this question has run its course already and isn't attracting any other answers, I'd suggest you state that particular problem in a new question.  If you post a comment here referring to the new question, I'll be able to know when you've posted it and take a look.